# Having trouble plotting location variable in R using googleVis package?

Tags: r

So I have this dataset of bike thefts (link: https://www.opendataphilly.org/dataset/bicycle-thefts/resource/f9809381-76f6-4fca-8279-621e088ddaa0).

I tried this code to plot location variable in R. the code runs, and i am taken to a new window but it is blank. Nothing appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I tried:

I renamed the dataset as bt

```
install.packages("ggmap")
library(ggmap)
install.packages("googleVis")
library(googleVis)    

bt$LOCATION_B <- as.character(bt$LOCATION_B)
bt$geom <- gsub(",", ":", bt$geom)
placeNames <- as.character(bt$LOCATION_B)    
plotData <- data.frame(name = placeNames, latLong = unlist(bt$geom))

sites <- gvisMap(plotData, locationvar = "latLong", tipvar = "name",
    options = list(displayMode = "Markers", mapType = "terrain", 
     colorAxis = "{colors:['red', 'blue']}", height = 600,
    useMapTypeControl=TRUE, enableScrollWheel='TRUE'))
```

plot(sites)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that

Comment: Did it work? or not?

Comment: No it still doesn't work. I tried it on safari and mozilla.